# ASP.NET Core Web API 6: Swagger example XML POST body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I have a ASP.NET Core Web API 6.0 project containing an endpoint which expects XML in its POST body (application/xml). I have created an attribute as follows:

```
using System;

/// <summary>
/// Used to mark an API for Swagger as having a raw XML body (Swagger creates an inout field).
/// </summary>
public class XmlPayloadAttribute : Attribute
{
    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    public XmlPayloadAttribute()
    {
        ParameterName = "payload";
        Required = true;
        MediaType = "application/xml";
        Format = "xml";
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    public string Format { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    public string MediaType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    public bool Required { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
}
```

...and a filter as follows:

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Any;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen; // Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 6.2.3

public class XmlPayloadFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var attribute = context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlPayloadAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
        if (attribute == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        operation.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody() { Required = true };
        var xml = @"<MyObject><Something/></MyObject>"; // How do I get this XML to appear as my example, verbatim?

        operation.RequestBody.Content.Add("application/xml", new OpenApiMediaType()
        {
            Schema = new OpenApiSchema()
            {
                Type = "string",
                Example = new OpenApiString(xml) // This doesn't work!
            },
            Example = new OpenApiString(xml) // This doesn't work either!
        });
    }
}
```

I add the `[XmlPayload]` annotation to my endpoint as shown here:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

/// <summary>
/// My controller.
/// </summary>
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// My Method.
    /// </summary>
    [Route("MyMethod")]
    [HttpPost]
    [XmlPayload]
    public IActionResult MyMethod()
    {
        using var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
        var content = reader.ReadToEndAsync().Result;

        // I deserialize and process the xml here

        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = /* My XML response goes here */,
            ContentType = "application/xml",
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK
        };
    }
}
```

Swagger correctly creates an input field for the post body, and correctly understands that the content type should be "application/xml", but populates the field with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- XML example cannot be generated; root element name is undefined -->
```

If I use `Name` as follows:

```
        operation.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody() { Required = true };
        var xml =
@"<s:MyRoot xmlns:s=""http://myschema"">
    <s:MyTag>
    </s:MyTag>
</s:MyRoot>";
        operation.RequestBody.Content.Add("application/xml", new OpenApiMediaType()
        {
            Schema = new OpenApiSchema()
            {
                Xml = new OpenApiXml
                {
                    Name = "MyRoot",
                    Namespace = new Uri("http://myschema")
                },
                Example = new OpenApiString(xml, true)
            },
        });
```

I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyRoot xmlns="http://myschema/">&lt;s:MyRoot 
xmlns:s=&quot;http://myschema&quot;&gt;
    &lt;s:MyTag&gt;
    &lt;/s:MyTag&gt;
&lt;/s:MyRoot&gt;</MyRoot>
```

I get the same result with or without `Namespace` and with or without setting the `isExplicit` parameter of `OpenApiString` to either true or false.

How do I get Swagger to display my XML string verbatim (how do I fix my C#)?

Comment: can you also add code  for your POST method ?

Comment: @CodingMytra I've edited my question to include the POST method

Comment: what you have in your request body is a string which looks like "xml" and you are trying to set a xml string as an example which swagger tries to convert to xml that's why it is failing. if you have defined structure of xml then try referencing that.

Comment: @CodingMytra Unfortunately, the schema is defined/driven by the client, and involves numerous namespaces. To accomodate the schema, I am deserializing the request body/serializing the response using `XmlSerializer`; my classes contain a lot of `[XmlNamespaceDeclarations]` markups. Given that I have raw XML examples at hand, it seems simpler to me to just tell Swagger to use a verbatim example than to create a very complex schema definition that only swagger will ever use for only one example. It's also not at all clear to me how to describe a schema to Swagger, even a simple one.

Answer (score 1):

```
operation.RequestBody.Content.Add("application/xml", new OpenApiMediaType()
{
    Schema = new OpenApiSchema()
    {
        Type = "string",
        Xml = new OpenApiXml()
        {
            Name = "<RootElementNameHere>"
        },
        Example = new OpenApiString(xml) // This doesn't work!
    },
    Example = new OpenApiString(xml) // This doesn't work either!
});
```

In order for the example to be displayed verbatim (without escaping), you need to add a DTO and generate its schema.

1. In the attribute class, add the properties Type and Example

```
    [AttributeUsage(validOn: AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class XmlPayloadAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public XmlPayloadAttribute(Type type, string? example = null)
        {
            ParameterName = "payload";
            Required = true;
            MediaType = "application/xml";
            Format = "xml";
            ParameterExample = example;
            ParameterType = type;
        }
        public string Format { get; set; }
        public string MediaType { get; set; }
        public bool Required { get; set; }
        public string ParameterName { get; set; }
        public Type ParameterType { get; set; }
        public string? ParameterExample { get; set; }
    }
```

2. In the Filter, add all the examples specified through the attributes to the method

```
    public class XmlPayloadFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        private string FormatXml(string xml)
        {
            try
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                return doc.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return xml;
            }
        }
    
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var attributes = context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlPayloadAttribute), false);
    
            if (attributes == null || attributes.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
    
            operation.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody() { Required = true };
    
            foreach (XmlPayloadAttribute attribute in attributes)
            {
                if (operation.RequestBody.Content.TryGetValue("application/xml", out var type))
                {
                    type.Examples.Add($"{attribute.ParameterType.Name}", new OpenApiExample() { Value = new OpenApiString(FormatXml(attribute.ParameterExample)) });
                }
                else
                {
                    operation.RequestBody.Content.Add(
                        "application/xml",
                        new OpenApiMediaType
                        {
                            Schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(attribute.ParameterType, context.SchemaRepository),
                            Examples = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiExample>
                            {
                                {
                                    $"{attribute.ParameterType.Name}", new OpenApiExample() { Value = new OpenApiString(FormatXml(attribute.ParameterExample)) }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

3. Use attribute like this

```
    [HttpPost("post")]
    [XmlPayload(typeof(DTOClass1), "<ExampleXml1>")]
    [XmlPayload(typeof(DTOClass2), "<ExampleXml2>")]
    [XmlPayload(typeof(DTOClass3), "<ExampleXml3>")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> post()
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Please see my latest edits where I tried your suggestion and the results.

Answer (score 0):

I can share my more/less completed solution. I suppose it can fit 90% (maybe more) of your APIs, but maybe you need to extend something (i.e. add namespaces), so you're welcome!

`SoapEnvelope.cs`

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class SoapEnvelope<T>
{
    [XmlElement]
    public SoapBody<T> Body { get; set; }
}

[XmlType(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class SoapBody<T>
{
    [XmlElement]
    public T Request { get; set; }
}
```

`SoapXmlSerializerInputFormatter.cs`

```
public class SoapXmlSerializerInputFormatter : XmlSerializerInputFormatter
{
    public SoapXmlSerializerInputFormatter(MvcOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override XmlSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type)
    {
        var inheritanceChain = type.GetInheritanceChain();
        var inheritance = inheritanceChain.FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(SoapEnvelope<>));
        if (type != typeof(SoapEnvelope<>) && inheritance == null)
            return base.CreateSerializer(type);

        var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

        var genericArguments = (inheritance ?? type).GetGenericArguments();
        if (genericArguments.Length != 1)
            return base.CreateSerializer(type);

        var genericType = genericArguments[0];

        // override [XmlRoot(***)] for Envelope
        var xmlRoolAttr = typeof(SoapEnvelope<>).GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<XmlRootAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        overrides.Add(type, new XmlAttributes() { XmlRoot = xmlRoolAttr });

        // override [XmlType(***)] for Body
        var xmlAttribute = new XmlAttributes();
        var xmlTypeAttr = genericType.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<XmlTypeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        xmlAttribute.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute() { ElementName = xmlTypeAttr.TypeName, Namespace = xmlTypeAttr?.Namespace });

        // override model (instead of 'Request') for nested object inside Body
        var propertyName = nameof(SoapBody<Type>.Request); // type doesn't matter here, we just need name
        var nestedType = typeof(SoapBody<>).MakeGenericType(genericType);
        overrides.Add(nestedType, propertyName, xmlAttribute);

        return new XmlSerializer(type, overrides);
    }
}
```

Add to `Startup`:

```
services
  .AddControllers(options =>
  {
    // support soap envelope xml
    options.InputFormatters.Add(new SoapXmlSerializerInputFormatter(options));
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
    options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", "application/xml");
  });

services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
  options.OperationFilter<XmlOperationFilter>();
  services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
});
```

`SoapTestRequest.cs`

```
public class SoapTestRequest : SoapEnvelope<TestRequest>
{
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root_test")]
[XmlType(TypeName = "TestRequest", Namespace = "http://www.test.com/some/namespace")]
private class TestRequest
{
  [XmlArray]
  public string[] Codes { get; set; }

  [XmlArray(ElementName = "local_tests")]
  [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "test")]
  public TestClass[] Tests { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass
{
  [XmlElement]
  public int StateId { get; set; }

  [XmlIgnore]
  public int Ignored { get; set; }

  [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "testName")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [XmlElement(ElementName = "testDescr")]
  public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

`XmlConsumesAttribute.cs`

```
public class XmlConsumesAttribute : ConsumesAttribute
{
    public Type RequestType { get; init; }

    public XmlConsumesAttribute(Type requestType) : base(requestType, "text/xml", "application/xml")
    {
        RequestType = requestType;
    }
}
```

`XmlOperationFilter.cs`

```
public class XmlOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var xmlConsume = context.MethodInfo
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlConsumesAttribute), false)
            .OfType<XmlConsumesAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (xmlConsume is not null)
        {
            operation.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody();
            operation.RequestBody.Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>();
            var media = new OpenApiMediaType()
            {
                Schema = GetXmlSchema(context, xmlConsume.RequestType)
            };
            foreach (var contentType in xmlConsume.ContentTypes)
            {
                operation.RequestBody.Content.Add(contentType, media);
            }
        }
    }

    private static OpenApiSchema GetXmlSchema(OperationFilterContext context, Type type)
    {
        var inheritance = type.GetInheritanceChain().FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(SoapEnvelope<>));
        return type == typeof(SoapEnvelope<>) || inheritance is not null
            ? GetEnvelopeSchema(context, inheritance.GetGenericArguments()[0])
            : GetSchema(context, type, type.GetCustomAttributes(false));
    }

    private static OpenApiSchema GetEnvelopeSchema(OperationFilterContext context, Type type)
    {
        return new OpenApiSchema
        {
            Xml = new OpenApiXml() { Name = "Envelope" },
            Type = "object",
            Properties =
            {
                { "body", new OpenApiSchema()
                    {
                        Xml = new OpenApiXml() { Name = "Body" },
                        Type = "object",
                        Properties =
                        {
                            { type.Name, GetSchema(context, type) }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private static OpenApiSchema GetSchema(OperationFilterContext context, Type type, object[] attributes = default)
    {
        var xmlAttribute = attributes?.OfType<XmlAttributeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (type.IsPrimitive
            || type == typeof(string)
            || type == typeof(decimal)
            || type == typeof(float))
        {
            var schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(type, context.SchemaRepository);
            schema.Xml = new OpenApiXml() { Name = xmlAttribute?.AttributeName, Attribute = xmlAttribute is not null };
            return schema;
        }

        if (type.IsEnum)
        {
            return new OpenApiSchema()
            {
                Xml = new OpenApiXml() { Name = xmlAttribute?.AttributeName, Attribute = xmlAttribute is not null },
                Type = "string",
                Enum = Enum.GetNames(type).Select(x => new OpenApiString(x)).Cast<IOpenApiAny>().ToList()
            };
        }

        if (type.IsArray)
        {
            return new OpenApiSchema()
            {
                Xml = new OpenApiXml() { Name = GetPropertyName(attributes), Wrapped = true },
                Type = "array",
                Items = GetSchema(context, type.GetElementType(), attributes?.OfType<XmlArrayItemAttribute>().Cast<object>().ToArray())
            };
        }

        if (type.IsClass || type.IsValueType)
        {
            return new OpenApiSchema()
            {
                Xml = new OpenApiXml() { Name = GetPropertyName(attributes) },
                Type = "object",
                Properties = type.GetProperties()
                    .Where(x => !x.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(x => x is XmlIgnoreAttribute))
                    .ToDictionary(
                        x => GetPropertyName(x.GetCustomAttributes(false), x.Name),
                        x => GetSchema(context, x.PropertyType, x.GetCustomAttributes(false))
                )
            };
        }

        return context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(type, context.SchemaRepository);
    }

    private static string GetPropertyName(object[] attributes = default, string propertyName = default)
    {
        var xmlArray = attributes?.OfType<XmlArrayAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlArray?.ElementName))
            return xmlArray.ElementName;

        var xmlArrayItem = attributes?.OfType<XmlArrayItemAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlArrayItem?.ElementName))
            return xmlArrayItem.ElementName;

        var xmlAttribute = attributes?.OfType<XmlAttributeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlAttribute?.AttributeName))
            return xmlAttribute.AttributeName;

        var xmlElement = attributes?.OfType<XmlElementAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlElement?.ElementName))
            return xmlElement.ElementName;

        var xmlRoot = attributes?.OfType<XmlRootAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlRoot?.ElementName))
            return xmlRoot.ElementName;

        return propertyName;
    }
}
```

`XmlRequestBodyLoggerMiddleware.cs`

```
public class XmlRequestBodyLoggerMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<XmlRequestBodyLoggerMiddleware> _logger;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public XmlRequestBodyLoggerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<XmlRequestBodyLoggerMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var endpoint = httpContext.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint;
        var xmlConsumes = endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<XmlConsumesAttribute>();
        var isXmlRequest = httpContext.Request.ContentLength > 0
            && xmlConsumes is not null;

        if (isXmlRequest)
        {
            await LogRequest(httpContext.Request);
        }

        await _next(httpContext);
    }

    private async Task LogRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            request.EnableBuffering();
            using var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true);
            var rawXml = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // rewinding the stream to 0
            _logger.LogInformation($"Original request raw xml: \n{rawXml}");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.LogError(exception, "Can't log original xml request (most likely callback)");
        }
    }
}

public static class XmlBodyLoggerExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseXmlRequestBodyLogger(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (app == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        return app.UseMiddleware<XmlRequestBodyLoggerMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

`WebhookController.cs`

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class WebhookController : ControllerBase
{
  [XmlConsumes(typeof(SoapEnvelope<TestRequest>))]
  [HttpPost("test", Name = nameof(TestAsync))]
  [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
  public async Task<ActionResult> TestAsync([FromBody] SoapEnvelope<TestRequest> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    // business stuff
    return NoContent();
  }

  [XmlConsumes(typeof(SoapTestRequest))]
  [HttpPost("soap-test", Name = nameof(SoapTestAsync))]
  [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
  public async Task<ActionResult> SoapTestAsync([FromBody] SoapTestRequest soapRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    // business stuff
    return NoContent();
  }
}
```

The latest state will be hosted at https://gist.github.com/dsharkou/72a7386bd6f5d75f38d2fc34561dcf34

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/997587

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34223196)

Comment: @InSync please review it again, now I've added code with the link of the latest state